# How to run parallel function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have two functions which keep running in a while loop

One of them is 'getdata', the other one is 'data_analysis'

data_analysis takes a few seconds and getdata takes a couple seconds

I need data_analysis use the latest available data, so I want to getdata keep running while data_analysis is running.

I have parallel computing toolbox 2017a

Comment: have a look at http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run `getdata` continously, and whenever an instance of `getdata` has finished, you want to run a `data_analysis` in parallel, right?

Then you'll want to run `getdata` in a while-loop, and call `data_analysis` to run in a parallel pool. The following code should do this:

```
p = gcp(); % builds a parallel pool
while true
    getdata(); % continuously runs the getdata function
    f = parfeval(p, @data_analysis, numOuts, args); % runs the data_analysis function
                                                % in the parallel pool
end
```

`numOut` is the number of outputs supplied by data_analysis.
`args` are the arguments to pass to data_analysis.

As Edric noted: at some point you also need to call `fetchOutputs` on `f` to retrieve the results.

If data_analysis doesn't return anything, the line `parfeval(p, @data_analysis, 0, args);` should be sufficient.

Disclaimer: I can't run matlab at the moment so I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: The correct syntax for the `parfeval` call would be: `f = parfeval(p, @data_analysis, numOut, args)`; where `numOut` is the number of outputs supplied by `data_analysis`. Of course, at some point you also need to call `fetchOutputs` on `f` to retrieve the results.